# I need help to write a method about arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I need to write a method that returns a new array by eliminating the duplicate values in the array. The order of appearances for numbers must not change.

What I tried so far:

```
public static int[] eliminateDuplicates(int[] array) {
     // Create a variable to count unique (non-duplicated) values.
        int numOfUnique = 0;

        // Create a boolean array for values in the array to be false if they are duplicated, or to              be true if they are not
        boolean[] isUnique = new boolean[array.length]; // All values assigned to be false
        Arrays.fill(isUnique, true); // All values assigned to be true
 
        // Determine if they are unique or not
        for(int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                if(array[j] == array[i]) {
                    isUnique[i] = false;
                    isUnique[j] = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(isUnique[i]) {
                numOfUnique++;
            }
        }

        int[] nonDuplicateArray = new int[numOfUnique];
        System.out.println(nonDuplicateArray.length);

        return nonDuplicateArray;
}
```

I know it is not finished yet. For now, I am trying to find out if I did correct so far. But the answer is no.

Edit:
The output:

Generated numbers with duplicate values are:
2       10      4       4       10      8       2       10      4       6
The number of non-duplicate Numbers is 4
Non duplicate numbers
8       6       0       0

It finds the non-duplicate values (8 and 6), but it add some extra zeros for no reason. That is why the length of the array is longer than expected. I don't know what to do.

Comment: And what is the question/problem?

Comment: It didn't work. I don't know what I can do. This is the problem.

Comment: Well, the obvious problem would be that you create a `nonDuplicateArray` but don't write anything into it - so that can't possibly contain the correct result

Comment: @UnholySheep I'll write the numbers into it. I am just testing that the number of unique values is true. But it is not. System.out.println(nonDuplicateArray.length) doesn't work as I expected. For example array is that { 1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5 }. It should write 1 but it doesn't.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "eliminating the duplicates"? Do you mean to make sure that each number occurs once in the array? Or do you want to remove all values that are not unique in the array? For example, for an input of `[1,2,3,3,3,4]`, do you want the output to be `[1,2,3,4]`, or `[1,2,4]`?

Answer (score 1):

I'll provide the short option using [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html).

```
public static int[] eliminateDuplicates(int[] array) {
    return IntStream.of(array).distinct().toArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You assume all of the itens are unique.

```
    // Create a variable to count unique (non-duplicated) values.
    int numOfUnique = 0;

    // Create a boolean array for values in the array to be false if they are duplicated, or to              be true if they are not
    boolean[] isUnique = new boolean[array.length]; // All values assigned to be false
    Arrays.fill(isUnique, true); // All values assigned to be true
```

And then you start on the second value and compare to all previous ones.

```
    // Determine if they are unique or not
    for(int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
```

If the value `i` at the moment matches with a previous value `j` you mark them as "not unique".

```
            if(array[j] == array[i]) {
                isUnique[i] = false;
                isUnique[j] = false;
                break;
            }
```

The count of the number of unique itens is correct

```
            if(isUnique[i]) {
                numOfUnique++;
            }
```

Now you know the lenght of the new array since it contains only unique numbers

```
        int[] nonDuplicateArray = new int[numOfUnique];
```

Question: Should the `array=[1,3,3,4]` be `nonDuplicateArray=[1,4]` or `nonDuplicateArray=[1,3,4]`?

In the second case, you won't know directly which of these itens you need to maintain because both the first appearance `j` as the second appearance `i` is set to false in your isUnique array.

In the example, `array=[1,3,3,4]` results in `isUnique=[true,false,false,true]`.

So you need to remove this line so the leftmost item `j` remains intact

```
                isUnique[j] = false;
```

With this change the `array=[1,3,3,4]` results in `isUnique=[true,true,false,true]`.

Ignore this whole suggestion if the `array=[1,3,3,4]` should be `nonDuplicateArray=[1,4]`

Finally, in the end of the code, you need to populate the new array `nonDuplicateArray` because current implementation have only allocated the memory.

For this, you could loop thought the original array to copy the values but skipping when `isUnique[i]` is false. Like this:

```
    int k = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { 
        if(isUnique[i])
             nonDuplicateArray[k++]=array[i];
```

Only after this population step you can show your new array

```
    System.out.println(nonDuplicateArray.length);
```

Comment: You say "The count of the number of unique items is correct". That is what I am asking. It is not. The answer I get is wrong.